# inluxis flv streaming (flash)

Tags: flash, stream, flv, rtmp

This time I'm building a flv player via RTMP, my server is influxis (.com).

I built a few months ago, a video player that streams through HTTP but that player doesn't work via RTMP, so I'm wondering if anybody has or known where can I get a sample fla file, in order to recognize elements and AS.

I just need play pause and stop actions, no volume, no seek bar etc.

Or if anybody knows how to build it any help any idea will be welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Is your player using a netstream connection? That should be all you need. When using streaming video you never use the flv extension, so the path should be: rmpt://location.com/applicationdirectory

See http://www.gotoandlearn.com for video player tutorials using netstream